# Undefined variable after giving the value in the constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having trouble with accessing a variable that I am using at the constructor `this.currentLang` as you can see it take the value and is the value is also outside the constructor but when the flow goes to `displayIndustries` function/method is `undefined` is anything going wrong for the scope of this variable cause I try with `boolean` and now with the string still `undefined`.

Comment: Looking at the code everything seems fine. Are you able to reproduce this on something like Stackblitz?

Comment: Have you declared `currentLang` inside the class, outside of constructor

Comment: `industry` is undefined, not `this.currentLang`

Comment: what do you get after assigning `the.currentLang` to `lang` with `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.currentLang))`

Comment: Do you call `displayIndustries` anywhere else?

Comment: Don't do work in the constructor. Use a debugger before you post your question and always share the details of any errors you get. Don't just post a question that says this code doesn't work.

Comment: Hi i have work in constructor because only this way i can handle the language change, i don't get any error just the value is undefined

Comment: @JamieRees I don't know how to use Stackblitz, but I will try to post a bit more code here

Comment: You call a function with out any arguments but all execution paths require that argument. The logic is impossible to satisfy.

Comment: What do you mean the parameter is optional ? as you can see. @Reactgular

Comment: You never pass a value for industry and it's defined with a question mark to tell the compiler that is optional. So there is no compiler error when none is passed. Every return statement will fail when its not passed.

Comment: Remove the call to displayIndustry because it doesn't do anything. There is no state change for the component. It's useless.

Comment: First is called by default has a parameter but from the counstructor, it doesn't have it, the problem for the moment isn't their butt at the variable that is coming undefined

Comment: Please use a debugger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194696/discussion-between-ilia-tapia-and-reactgular).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the variable in the constructor. You are using it inside a subscription callback that is asynchronously called after/during the constructor call. To prevent `currentLang` from being undefined, you can initialise it.

```
  currentLang = ''

  constructor(
       private fb: FormBuilder, 
       private langService: LangService ,
       private translate: TranslateService
  ) {

    this.langService.currentLang.subscribe((lang) => {
      this.currentLang = lang;
      this.showCurrentLang = this.currentLang === 'en';
      if (this.AfterDisplayIndustries) {
        this.displayIndustries();
      }
    });
  }


  displayIndustries (industry?: IIndustry) {
    this.AfterDisplayIndustries = true;
    return (this.currentLang === 'en' && industry) ? industry.name : industry.nameCZ;
  }
```

(I also made your code concise)